# Return function, really confused

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and I'm pretty much learning off other people's code and incorporating it into mine so my apologies for the ugliness.

I have this variable `random_collector = ''`. As the code goes on I've set `random_collector` to a non-blank string. At the very end I've set a Return function for `random_collector`. The question is : **will it return a blank string or a non-blank string**?

```
def add_csv():
    random_collector = ''
    sitevalue = ''
    path = raw_input('path to csv file: ')
    with open(path, 'r') as ifile:
        reader = csv.reader(ifile)
        reader.next()
        for row in reader:
            deviceip = row[1]
            displayname = row[0]
            snmpc = row[2]
            alert_priority = row[3]
            monitoring_templates = row[4]
            pd_alert_service = row[5]
            site_code = row[6]
            team_owner = row[7]
            if displayname_pattern.match(displayname):
                cut_displayname = displayname[0:4]
                print cut_displayname
                if cut_displayname in site:
                    sitevalue = site.get(cut_displayname)
                    cut_office = cut_displayname[0:3]
                    if cut_office in na_office:
                        random_collector = random.choice(na_collector)
                        lm_add_api(deviceip, displayname, random_collector, sitevalue, snmpc, alert_priority, monitoring_templates, pd_alert_service, site_code, team_owner)
                        time.sleep(5)
                    elif cut_office in apac_office:
                        random_collector = random.choice(apac_office)
                        lm_add_api(deviceip, displayname, random_collector, sitevalue, snmpc, alert_priority, monitoring_templates, pd_alert_service, site_code, team_owner)
                    elif cut_office in emea_office:
                        random_collector = random.choice(emea_office)
                        lm_add_api(deviceip, displayname, random_collector, sitevalue, snmpc)
                else:
                    print 'Site format is not a recongnized'
                    time.sleep(2)
                    add()
            else:
                print 'Double check the site code, device group not found in Logic Monitor'
                time.sleep(2)
                add()

    return deviceip, displayname, random_collector, sitevalue, snmpc, alert_priority, monitoring_templates, pd_alert_service, site_code, team_owner
```

The second part of my confusion in this block of code is I'm calling another function called `lm_add_api(deviceip, displayname, random_collector, sitevalue, snmpc, alert_priority, monitoring_templates, pd_alert_service, site_code, team_owner)` and it's taking the variable random_collector. Is it taking the variable from the Return or the result from `random_collector = random.choice(na_collector)`?

```
if cut_office in na_office:
                        random_collector = random.choice(na_collector)
                        lm_add_api(deviceip, displayname, random_collector, sitevalue, snmpc, alert_priority, monitoring_templates, pd_alert_service, site_code, team_owner)
```

Comment: If you want to know what it returns, why don't you run it and see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value for random_collector returned will be whatever value is stored in that variable at the time of return.  If the code gets to and executes one of the lines of code assigning a value to random_collector, that will be the returned value.  If not, it will keep the initial value you gave it (empty string).

For the second question, you are calling lm_add_api with the value you get back from `random.choice(na_collector)`.

It is important to note that Python, like other imperative programming languages, changes state as the code executes and maintains the updated state values.  So any time you change the value of a variable, it keeps that updated value.  Code like:

```
x = 1
x = 2
x = 3
x = 4
print x
```

will simply print '4'.  All those earlier assignments are overwritten.